# Javascript accessing ejs variable in Node.js context

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

*I am trying my javascript code inside an HTML file to access an ejs variable.*

This is the Node.js code:

```
res.render('target.ejs', {data:user});
```

When i do this in HTML:

```
<p> <h1><%= data %></h1> </p>
```

evertything is ok.

But when I try to access the variable inside a `<script>`, like this:

```
<script>
    var name = <%= data %>;
    alert(name);
</script>
```

then nothing happens. I also tried with a `console.log(name);` and still it didn't work.

Comment: View Source ... is your friend. Your browser should show the html generated by node / ejs.

Comment: I want the variables to be accessible in Javascript. I don't know if they can be seen inside <script>. Neither alert, nor console.log() is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need some quotes.

Try

```
  var name = '<%= data %>';
```